# Configuring Parse-Server with HTTPS in Express

Tags: node.js, parse-server

Running Express.js + Parse Server and trying to configure HTTPS on the Parse API route with the 'https' JS library.

- Code snippet

  ```
  var https = require('https');
  ....
  https.createServer(config.certificate,app).listen(port,function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
  });
  // This will enable the Live Query real-time server
  ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(https);
  ```
- Steps to recreate

  1. Install the proper libs

     Using: Node (4.5), https (1.0.0)
  2. Run "node index.js"
- Expected results

  Server should start with no problems running on an HTTPS port
  `https://mydomainhere:4444/parse`
- Actual outcome

  ```
  ~/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:401
  throw err;
  ^
  TypeError: this._server.once is not a function
  at new WebSocketServer (~/parse/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocketServer.js:78:18)
  at new ParseWebSocketServer (~/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/LiveQuery/ParseWebSocketServer.js:26:13)
  at new ParseLiveQueryServer (~/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/LiveQuery/ParseLiveQueryServer.js:103:33)
  at Function.createLiveQueryServer (~/parse/node_modules/parse-server/lib/ParseServer.js:429:14)
  at Object. (~/parse/parse.js:63:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
  ```
- Environment setup

  Using: Node (4.5), https (1.0.0), parse-server ( "2.2.22"), Linux Centos

Answer (score 2):

Although this question was asked long ago, I am trying to answer this question for the future readers as no appropriate answer was posted.

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/parse', // Connection string for your MongoDB database
    appId: 'your app id',
    masterKey: 'your app master key', // Keep this key secret!
    serverURL: 'https://localhost:1337/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
};

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(options,app);

httpsServer.listen(1337, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault and thanks for this answer! You could make this even more useful by explaining it a little.

Comment: I got error: Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch How to generate certificates? I have .key certificates

Comment: I generate certificates with letsencrypt and I didn't know which file it needed in the cert field: fullchain.pem
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and reported an issue with parse-server.

Flovilmart helped with that and found out that the right way to do that is to declare a new variable for the https server. In your example you would use:

```
var https = require('https');
....
var httpsServer = https.createServer(config.certificate,app).listen(port,function() {
console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

This will enable the Live Query real-time server
`ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpsServer);`

you can see the full conversation here: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3165#event-881061654